# Recover accidentally deleted photos not shown in recently deleted

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, recovery

I accidentally deleted a photo, and it does not show in the "recently deleted" folder. Is there any way I can get it back? I have iOS 8.2.

Comment: Do you have a backup? If yes, you find it and copy the photo from that backup. If you don't have a backup or if you weren't connected to your iTunes on a PC when deleting it, then it is probably gone

Comment: Are you sure you got it deleted? I'm asking because you're saying "accidentally" so it looks like you're not sure what happened and you assumed you deleted it. As it's not in your "Recently deleted" folder, are you sure you didn't just hide it?

Answer (score 1):

Their is no way you can recover a photo after deleting it from recently deleted unless you have a backup

Answer (score -1):

Unless you're ***jailbroken***, there's no way to recover them if you don't have a backup.

Comment: Could you expand your answer to detail how a jailbreak helps here?