# Apple restore problem

Tags: icloud, photos

I accidentally deleted a photo from the "Recently Deleted" album and I need it back. I have an iCloud back-up but every time I restore the back-up, the photo is not in the gallery and I know for sure that the back-up was made before I deleted the photo.

Is there any possibility that I can recover the photo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recover accidentally deleted photos not shown in recently deleted](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193404/recover-accidentally-deleted-photos-not-shown-in-recently-deleted)

Comment: Not sure it's a dupe. The potential dupe answer is 'recover it from a backup' This question is 'what happens if it's not in the backup'

Answer (score 1):

If your using iCloud Photo Library your photos aren't part of your iCloud device backup, because the photos are stored in iCloud anyway.

The only chance to get it back is via a Mac, that downloaded the library via Photos.app and to check it's backups.

Comment: This is true, additionally try disconnecting your Mac from Internet (assuming you have one linked to your iCloud Photo Library), then open the Photos app. Check for the photo on your library (with Wifi still off). If it's not there then you might be out of luck.